# D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use

Tags: bluetooth

How to resolve issue mentioned as title?

Trying to execute below command (with bluez-5.37 and Ubuntu 14.04):

```
brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ sudo ./bluetoothd --plugin=time -n
bluetoothd[29255]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[29255]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, the message means that another/running daemon is using the same bus name.

- Check using:

  ```
  $ ps aux | grep blue
  sneetsh+  2226  0.0  0.0 333592  5432 ?        Ssl  08:00   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service
  sneetsh+  2318  0.0  0.6 605972 48636 ?        Sl   08:00   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet
  sneetsh+  2765  0.0  0.0  31484  3348 ?        S    08:00   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd
  root      5327  0.0  0.0  29864  4504 ?        Ss   09:03   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
  sneetsh+  5361  0.0  0.0   9592  2192 pts/2    S+   09:04   0:00 grep --color=auto blue
  ```

  Or system monitor (graphic user interface).
- Another option, `d-feet`, it is DBus browser. In the bottom left corner, you can see the owner process.

  [image: d-feet get DBUS owner PID and Command]

Then `sudo kill` it or `sudo service ... stop` it if it's service. For default Ubuntu setup, it has a service, so run:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
sudo service bluetooth stop
```

Run your local daemon then enable bluetooth again

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Without switching of bluetooth, the bluetooth service will re-spawn again.

Comment: I have killed /usr/sbin/bluetoothd process

Comment: brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ sudo killall -9 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ sudo ./bluetoothd --plugin=time -n
bluetoothd[9202]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[9202]: Unable to get on D-Bus

Comment: brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ sudo killall -9 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd

brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ sudo ./bluetoothd --plugin=time -n

bluetoothd[9202]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37

D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use

bluetoothd[9202]: Unable to get on D-Bus

Comment: brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ d-feet
 
error getting unix process id for org.freedesktop.DBus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get PID of name 'org.freedesktop.DBus': no such name
error getting unix process id for org.freedesktop.DBus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get PID of name 'org.freedesktop.DBus': no such name

Comment: <h1>tried d-feet as suggested<\h1>

<h2>brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ d-feet</h2>
 
<h3>error getting unix process id for org.freedesktop.DBus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get PID of name 'org.freedesktop.DBus': no such name</h3>
<h4>error getting unix process id for org.freedesktop.DBus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get PID of name 'org.freedesktop.DBus': no such name</h4>

Comment: i am trying to post comment with right format, sorry for my previous comment not in proper format.  I am learning

Comment: @brijesh [edit] the question instead, comment are just for short discussion

Comment: @brijesh , it brings for me warning too, but it works a s it should be. Did it show its windows?

Comment: Killed the bluestoothd and stopped bluetooth service and tried again.
brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ sudo killall -9 bluetoothd 
brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
 * Stopping bluetooth                                                                                                                    [ OK ] 
brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$ sudo ./bluetoothd --plugin=time -n
bluetoothd[19242]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[19242]: Unable to get on D-Bus
brij@brij:~/Downloads/bluez-5.37/src$

Comment: still facing the same issue. d-feet launched the window but how to use it?

Comment: I want to execute plugin

Comment: $ sudo ./bluetoothd --plugin=time -n

Comment: successfully, please suggest.

Comment: @brijesh updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for your great help and something got resolved but facing another error on $ sudo ./bluetoothd --plugin=time -n

Comment: bluetoothd[1784]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
bluetoothd[1784]: Not enough free handles to register service
bluetoothd[1784]: Current Time Service could not be registered
bluetoothd[1784]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
bluetoothd[1784]: hci0 Load Connection Parameters failed: Unknown Command (0x01)

Comment: <h1> @Sneetsher </h1>

Comment: @brijesh That another separate problem, you could post new question, add much info to support it and to have more chance to get answer. BTW, Would you accept & up vite my answer as it works for you, see https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers