# Unable to switch off bluetooth [xubuntu 16.04]

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

This is an extention of another question:
[D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723671/d-bus-setup-failed-name-already-in-use)

I have the same problem. Trying to execute below command (with bluez-5.37 and Xubuntu 16.04):

```
~/tmp/bluez/bluez-5.37$ sudo ./src/bluetoothd -n -E --plugin=audio
bluetoothd[12453]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[12453]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

The answer for the question mentioned above suggests either to kill the process or stop the service:

```
sudo kill
sudo service ... stop
rfkill block bluetooth
sudo service bluetooth stop
```

But no matter what I do, the bluetooth service re-spawns again at the same moment I stop it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For a `systemd` based init system, it *should* be `sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service` I think - have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, tried it. The same result: bluetooth service re-spawns again.