# Bluetooth can't find headphones

Tags: command-line, sound, bluetooth, 18.10, a2dp

When I activate bluetooth on my notebook I can see and pair with every bluetooth device near me but there is no A2DP or HFP/HSP headphones in there. Typing 
`service bluetooth status`
in terminal gives me back

```
    bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-11-07 12:35:12 MSK; 1h 2min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1189 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4331)
   Memory: 2.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1189 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

ноя 07 12:35:10 r3t4rd-K56CB systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
ноя 07 12:35:11 r3t4rd-K56CB bluetoothd[1189]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
ноя 07 12:35:12 r3t4rd-K56CB systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
ноя 07 12:35:12 r3t4rd-K56CB bluetoothd[1189]: Starting SDP server
ноя 07 12:35:13 r3t4rd-K56CB bluetoothd[1189]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
ноя 07 12:35:28 r3t4rd-K56CB bluetoothd[1189]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
ноя 07 12:35:28 r3t4rd-K56CB bluetoothd[1189]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.50 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
ноя 07 13:31:50 r3t4rd-K56CB bluetoothd[1189]: Unable to get io data for :1.50/Profile/HSPHSProfile/00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb:
```

Full restart of bluetooth service and typing `service bluetooth status` again just removed last line from the feedback.
I'm new to Linux systems so I can't get what to do next, can you lead me?

Answer (score 1):

killing org.bluez process through `sudo kill <org.bluez PID>`,

then I wrote

```
rfkill block bluetooth
sudo service bluetooth stop
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Bluetooth have been swithed off and then on after typing these commands, and my headphones appeared in devices list. [Thanks to that answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723671/d-bus-setup-failed-name-already-in-use)