# Help to configure USB Bluetoth adapter on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth, 20.10

### Description

Bought a Bluetooth USB adapter from AliExpress, and trying to set up it on my Ubuntu machine. Could someone help with it? Ready to provide any logs, just let me know in comments.

> NOTE: It's not a laptop, it's PC

I have typical symptoms:

1. Plugged in adapter
2. Open Bluetooth GUI menu
3. Tried to turn on Bluetooth, but nothing happen

[image]

I already checked few answers on SO, but nothing helpful.
Thanks in advance!

### Logs

1. `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list; uname -r; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

   ```sh
   00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
       DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
       Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [1458:e000]
       Kernel driver in use: e1000e
       Kernel modules: e1000e
   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] [10de:1c02] (rev a1)
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
   Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:62f1 Microdia USB 2.0 Camera
   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 256c:006e  
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
   Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   1: hci0: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
   5.8.0-44-generic
   [    0.095153] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
   [    7.098296] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
   [    7.117587] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
   [ 9190.046929] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
   [ 9190.046946] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
   [ 9190.046949] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
   [ 9190.046950] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
   [ 9190.046952] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
   [ 9190.056876] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
   [ 9190.097840] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
   [ 9190.097841] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
   [ 9190.097844] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
   [15290.811144] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
   ```
2. `bluetoothctl`

   ```sh
   Agent registered
   [bluetooth]# list
   [bluetooth]# devices
   No default controller available
   [bluetooth]# scan on
   No default controller available
   [bluetooth]# power on
   No default controller available
   ```
3. `sudo systemctl status bluetooth`

   ```
   ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
        Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
        Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-02-28 13:19:48 EET; 1h 9min ago
          Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
      Main PID: 1171 (bluetoothd)
        Status: "Running"
         Tasks: 1 (limit: 19054)
        Memory: 2.3M
        CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
                └─1171 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

   лют 28 13:19:47 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   лют 28 13:19:47 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   лют 28 13:19:47 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   лют 28 13:19:47 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   лют 28 13:19:47 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   лют 28 13:19:47 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   лют 28 13:19:47 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   лют 28 13:19:48 alexandrtovmach systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
   лют 28 13:19:48 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: Starting SDP server
   лют 28 13:19:48 alexandrtovmach bluetoothd[1171]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
   ```
4. `sudo /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -n -d`

   ```
   bluetoothd[16969]: Bluetooth daemon 5.55
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DiscoverableTimeout” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “AlwaysPairable” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “PairableTimeout” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Privacy” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “JustWorksRepairing” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “TemporaryTimeout” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Name” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Class” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DeviceID” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ReverseServiceDiscovery” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have group “Controller”
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:adapter_init() sending read version command
   bluetoothd[16969]: Starting SDP server
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/sdpd-service.c:register_device_id() Adding device id record for 0002:1d6b:0246:0537
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Loading builtin plugins
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading hostname plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading wiimote plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading autopair plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading policy plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading a2dp plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading avrcp plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading network plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading input plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading hog plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading gap plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading scanparam plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading deviceinfo plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading battery plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Loading plugins /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bluetooth/plugins
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading sixaxis plugin
   bluetoothd[16969]: profiles/input/suspend-none.c:suspend_init() 
   bluetoothd[16969]: profiles/network/manager.c:read_config() /etc/bluetooth/network.conf: Key file does not have key “DisableSecurity” in group “General”
   bluetoothd[16969]: profiles/network/manager.c:read_config() Config options: Security=true
   bluetoothd[16969]: plugins/hostname.c:read_dmi_fallback() chassis: desktop
   bluetoothd[16969]: plugins/hostname.c:read_dmi_fallback() major: 0x01 minor: 0x01
   bluetoothd[16969]: plugins/sixaxis.c:sixaxis_init() 
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:main() Entering main loop
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/rfkill.c:rfkill_event() RFKILL event idx 0 type 2 op 0 soft 0 hard 0
   bluetoothd[16969]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:read_version_complete() sending read supported commands command
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:read_version_complete() sending read index list command
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:read_commands_complete() Number of commands: 70
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:read_commands_complete() Number of events: 37
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:read_commands_complete() enabling kernel-side connection control
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:read_commands_complete() kernel supports the set_blocked_keys op
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:read_commands_complete() kernel supports exp features
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/adapter.c:read_index_list_complete() Number of controllers: 0
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.143
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Message Notification"
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.143
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Message Access"
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.143
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Phone Book Access"
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.143
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Synchronization"
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.143
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "File Transfer"
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.143
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Object Push"
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.143
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created ":1.143/org/bluez/obex/00005005_0000_1000_8000_0002ee000001/00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001"
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.77
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Headset Voice gateway"
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.77
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Headset unit"
   bluetoothd[16969]: plugins/hostname.c:property_changed() static hostname: alexandrtovmach
   bluetoothd[16969]: plugins/hostname.c:property_changed() pretty hostname: 
   bluetoothd[16969]: plugins/hostname.c:property_changed() chassis: desktop
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:add_default_agent() Default agent set to :1.151 /org/bluez/agent
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x5594518e0220: ref=1
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:register_agent() agent :1.151
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_disconnect() Agent :1.151 disconnected
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:remove_default_agent() Default agent cleared
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_destroy() agent :1.151
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x5594518e0220: ref=0
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:add_default_agent() Default agent set to :1.152 /org/bluez/agent
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x5594518e0220: ref=1
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:register_agent() agent :1.152
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_disconnect() Agent :1.152 disconnected
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:remove_default_agent() Default agent cleared
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_destroy() agent :1.152
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x5594518e0220: ref=0
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:add_default_agent() Default agent set to :1.153 /org/bluez/agent
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x5594518e0220: ref=1
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:register_agent() agent :1.153
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_disconnect() Agent :1.153 disconnected
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:remove_default_agent() Default agent cleared
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_destroy() agent :1.153
   bluetoothd[16969]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x5594518e0220: ref=0
   ```
5. `hciconfig`

   ```
   hci0: Type: Primary  Bus: USB
         BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13  ACL MTU: 679:8  SCO MTU: 48:16
         DOWN 
         RX bytes:367 acl:0 sco:0 events:12 errors:0
         TX bytes:37 acl:0 sco:0 commands:12 errors:0
   ```
6. `hciconfig -a hci0`

   ```
   hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
           BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13  ACL MTU: 679:8  SCO MTU: 48:16
           DOWN 
           RX bytes:367 acl:0 sco:0 events:12 errors:0
           TX bytes:37 acl:0 sco:0 commands:12 errors:0
           Features: 0xbf 0x3e 0x4d 0xfa 0xdb 0x3d 0x7b 0xc7
           Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
           Link policy: 
           Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
   ```

Comment: Buy an Iogear GBU521, those CSR dongles are hit and miss in Linux

Comment: Thanks! There are no guarantees that GBU521 will work properly on Linux (at least no official notes)

Comment: I have had 2 of them and they have worked.  They are really small and easy to misplace.  They show up as ID 0a5c:21e8 and may need the firmware from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd depending on what you are using bluetooth for

Comment: Even if not a guarantee, did you try the dongle in Win 10?

Comment: yep, it works fine in Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [official documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsBluetoothUsbAdapters),
please post the output of ([ref](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/hciconfig.8.html))

```
$ lsusb               *** You already did
$ hciconfig
$ hciconfig -a hci0   *** As this appears to be your bluetooth device
```

Plus, there are a few posts on issues with the device with the same [Vendor ID/Device ID](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/0A12/device/0001) numbers as yours (0a12:0001).

1. [Bluetooth adapter configuration issue (ID 0a12:0001)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208296/bluetooth-adapter-configuration-issue-id-0a120001). Note the answers, which, aside from requiring you trying somewhat cumbersome procedures, they are encouraging as for the chances of you getting the dongle up and going. It is not worth reposting here the solutions, as they are in askubuntu.
2. https://gist.github.com/nevack/6b36b82d715dc025163d9e9124840a07
3. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=257372
4. https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/320630-sierra-bluetooth-usb-dongle-0x0a120x0001-doesnt-work-cheap/ (info related to Mac, only *perhaps* useful)

**Related**

1. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581539
2. https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855812/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-which-bluetooth-device-is-plugged-into-which-usb-port

Comment: I patched kernel (but it was unnecessary, because I have the latest one with this patch). Thanks for all of these resources, I found many interesting things, but I still can's solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### Diagnosis

Your output shows problems parsing `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` for example this:

```
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DiscoverableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “AlwaysPairable” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “PairableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Privacy” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “JustWorksRepairing” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “TemporaryTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Name” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Class” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DeviceID” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ReverseServiceDiscovery” in group “General”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[16969]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
```

#### Solution

Back up `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` like so:

```
sudo mv /etc/bluetooth/main.conf /etc/bluetooth/main.conf.old
```

Then create a new `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Then copy and paste this into the file editor:

```
[General]

# Default adaper name
# Defaults to 'BlueZ X.YZ'
#Name = BlueZ

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
# considered. Defaults to '0x000000'.
#Class = 0x000100

# How long to stay in discoverable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 180, i.e. 3 minutes.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay discoverable forever
#DiscoverableTimeout = 0

# How long to stay in pairable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 0.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay pairable forever
#PairableTimeout = 0

# Automatic connection for bonded devices driven by platform/user events.
# If a platform plugin uses this mechanism, automatic connections will be
# enabled during the interval defined below. Initially, this feature
# intends to be used to establish connections to ATT channels. Default is 60.
#AutoConnectTimeout = 60

# Use vendor id source (assigner), vendor, product and version information for
# DID profile support. The values are separated by ":" and assigner, VID, PID
# and version.
# Possible vendor id source values: bluetooth, usb (defaults to usb)
#DeviceID = bluetooth:1234:5678:abcd

# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. This option is really only needed for qualification since the BITE tester
# doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases (though there could in
# theory be other useful purposes for this too). Defaults to 'true'.
#ReverseServiceDiscovery = true

# Enable name resolving after inquiry. Set it to 'false' if you don't need
# remote devices name and want shorter discovery cycle. Defaults to 'true'.
#NameResolving = true

# Enable runtime persistency of debug link keys. Default is false which
# makes debug link keys valid only for the duration of the connection
# that they were created for.
#DebugKeys = false

# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
#ControllerMode = dual

# Enables Multi Profile Specification support. This allows to specify if
# system supports only Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) configuration
# or both Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) and Multiple Profiles Multiple
# Devices (MPMD) configurations.
# Possible values: "off", "single", "multiple"
#MultiProfile = off

# Permanently enables the Fast Connectable setting for adapters that
# support it. When enabled other devices can connect faster to us,
# however the tradeoff is increased power consumptions. This feature
# will fully work only on kernel version 4.1 and newer. Defaults to
# 'false'.
#FastConnectable = false

[Policy]

# The ReconnectUUIDs defines the set of remote services that should try
# to be reconnected to in case of a link loss (link supervision
# timeout). The policy plugin should contain a sane set of values by
# default, but this list can be overridden here. By setting the list to
# empty the reconnection feature gets disabled.
#ReconnectUUIDs=00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

# ReconnectAttempts define the number of attempts to reconnect after a link
# lost. Setting the value to 0 disables reconnecting feature.
#ReconnectAttempts=7

# ReconnectIntervals define the set of intervals in seconds to use in between
# attempts.
# If the number of attempts defined in ReconnectAttempts is bigger than the
# set of intervals the last interval is repeated until the last attempt.
#ReconnectIntervals=1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64

# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
# This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged
# in later on. Defaults to 'false'.
AutoEnable=true
```

Then save the file and close the file editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> then press <kbd>y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After that, reboot your system and test your device.

**If you are connecting the device to an external USB hub, consider connecting it directly to the USB port in the PC instead.**

Comment: Thanks for answer. I updated this config file, and faced with https://askubuntu.com/questions/723671/d-bus-setup-failed-name-already-in-use

Comment: Resolved by suggested answer, and right now my `sudo /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -n -d` logs looks okay, but dongle still doesn't work. In `hciconfig` I see that's "DOWN"

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Did you reboot? What does `bluetoothctl devices` return?

Comment: bluetoothctl devices -> "No default controller available"

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach You need to run `sudo service bluetooth start` after the solution you followed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/723671/d-bus-setup-failed-name-already-in-use to bring the service up again. Or just reboot.

Comment: of course, I did it, but still no luck =/ and devices list empty

Comment: I also tried to run `sudo /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -n -d` to see any errors during bluetooth service initialization, but as I said everything looks okay after your suggestion. It looks more like problem with dongle drivers

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach run `sudo hciconfig hci0 up`.

Comment: `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` -> "Can't init device hci0: Invalid argument (22)"

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Disconnect device, reboot your machine then reconnect device after reboot and login completes. After that run `sudo hciconfig` and note your device ID then run `sudo hciconfig ID up` change `ID` with your device id for example `hci0`. If after that you still get `Can't init device hci0: Invalid argument (22)` then it is confirmed, kernel drivers issue and you need to find the driver for that device and install it. Good thing though, original issue is solved and if you now connect a supported Bluetooth device, it will work while before fixing, it wouldn't.

Comment: go through these steps, and yeah ― still "Can't init device hci0: Invalid argument (22)". Not sure if "original issue" solved, because config parsing it's just a part of the issue.

Comment: I saw a lot of patches for kernel drivers, but none of them works, and I still can't run my dongle. Would you suggest something how can I fix it?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Drivers are device specific and some drives simply do not exist on some OSs. Devices and chips get manufactured before and after OS release and some are supported while others are not. Most patches implementations involve extensive research and trial / error. Unfortunately I don't knew of a straightforward driver solution.  Officially supported devices are [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsBluetoothUsbAdapters), but even these wouldn't have worked without fixing `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` first. :)

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach I searched for the name of your device "CSR" and [this](https://gist.github.com/nevack/6b36b82d715dc025163d9e9124840a07) showed up. There is no guarantee it will work for you but it seems promising.

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach In particular [this reply](https://gist.github.com/nevack/6b36b82d715dc025163d9e9124840a07#gistcomment-3447545) where only updating the kernel solves it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the bluetooth is active and running.  `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`  Been awhile sense I used Ubuntu service maybe named slightly different.

If it is not active and running you'll need to enable and start the service.

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

Then try blueoothctl again.

EDIT: (Does not really effect you but for other in the future who may read this) If this is a laptop make sure there is not a hardware switch alot of laptops have them usually it is something like Control or Alt maybe Function and one of the F keys.  And there are a couple laptops that actually have physical switches on them very few but they are out there.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. Seems like `bluetooth` service is running normally. Added logs to answer.